# SwiftUI - Can I share functions with an extracted subview?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm extracting subviews to keep my code manageable but one thing I've come up against is not being able to call functions in the parent view. Can someone explain to me the best practice for this please?

Here's a pseudo-example:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    func performAction(){
        //do something here
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {        
            MySubView()
        }
    }
}

struct MySubView(){
    HStack {
        Button(action: {
            // I want to call performAction() here
        }) {
            Text("Perform action")
        }
    }
}
```

One option I've considered is using a binding and then performing the action in the setter of the bound variable, but that seems ungainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `extension`:

```
struct MyView: View {
    func performAction() {
        // do something here
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            subView
        }
    }
}

extension MyView {
    var subView: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.performAction()
            }) {
                Text("Perform action")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach, actually the same as you observe for standard Button - by injecting action into sub-view constructor:

```
struct MyView: View {

    func performAction(){
        //do something here
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MySubView(action: performAction)
            // or 
    //        MySubView { 
    //           performAction()
    //           // ... and another action
    //        }
        }
    }
}

struct MySubView: View {
    let action: () -> ()

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: action) {
                Text("Perform action")
            }
        }
    }
}
```