# Best practices for SwiftUI state variable encapsulation/ Too many state variables in a complicated view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-state

I'm use to have a class for several complex subviews in a view. Each can encapsulate it's own state.  SwiftUI will let you refactor a long view function into subviews but I have not found anything other than passing `@Binding` variables through the views.

I keep ending up with a lot of state variables on the main view. Ideally what I would like would be if I could reference a subview of the main and directly set it's state like this

`mainView.bottomPane.odometer.speed = 55`

Is this possible? If not are there other ways around large chunks of State variables in the main form?

Comment: This might help you: [SwiftUI - Can I share functions with an extracted subview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63428497/8697793)

Comment: Your example code sounds as it should be in view model instead of state. But to make it clear would you provide minimal example?